# How to get the the data-preconnect-urls using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am using HTMLAgilityPack and I'm trying to scrape the link **http://www.hundsun.co.jp/** which is under the *data-preconnect-urls*. How can I get that?

```
  <h3>
  <a style="display:none" href="/aclk?sa=L&amp;ai=DChcSEwimnPnc5OvQAhWRl70KHcxqCEAYABAA&amp;ei=9hZNWLqlCIyY8gXA04vACg&amp;sig=AOD64_3SZuXd57_-qOs8nnhn8rqw8GlIgw&amp;q=&amp;sqi=2&amp;ved=0ahUKEwi6-PTc5OvQAhUMjLwKHcDpAqgQ0QwIGA&amp;adurl=" id="s0p1c0"></a>
  <a href="https://www.google.co.jp/aclk?sa=L&amp;ai=DChcSEwimnPnc5OvQAhWRl70KHcxqCEAYABAA&amp;ei=9hZNWLqlCIyY8gXA04vACg&amp;sig=AOD64_3SZuXd57_-qOs8nnhn8rqw8GlIgw&amp;q=&amp;sqi=2&amp;ved=0ahUKEwi6-PTc5OvQAhUMjLwKHcDpAqgQ0QwIGA&amp;adurl=" id="vs0p1c0" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)" data-preconnect-urls="http://www.hundsun.co.jp/" jsl="$t t-zxXzjt1d4B0;$x 0;" class="r-iA_xzYkgkx2Y">ブリッジSE募集中 - hundsun.co.jp‎</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    using System;
    using HtmlAgilityPack;
    using System.Xml;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()       
        {
            string html = "<html><body><h3><a style=\"display:none\" href=\"/aclk?sa=L&amp;ai=DChcSEwimnPnc5OvQAhWRl70KHcxqCEAYABAA&amp;ei=9hZNWLqlCIyY8gXA04vACg&amp;sig=AOD64_3SZuXd57_-qOs8nnhn8rqw8GlIgw&amp;q=&amp;sqi=2&amp;ved=0ahUKEwi6-PTc5OvQAhUMjLwKHcDpAqgQ0QwIGA&amp;adurl=\" id=\"s0p1c0\"></a><a href=\"https://www.google.co.jp/aclk?sa=L&amp;ai=DChcSEwimnPnc5OvQAhWRl70KHcxqCEAYABAA&amp;ei=9hZNWLqlCIyY8gXA04vACg&amp;sig=AOD64_3SZuXd57_-qOs8nnhn8rqw8GlIgw&amp;q=&amp;sqi=2&amp;ved=0ahUKEwi6-PTc5OvQAhUMjLwKHcDpAqgQ0QwIGA&amp;adurl=\" id=\"vs0p1c0\" onmousedown=\"return google.arwt(this)\" data-preconnect-urls=\"http://www.hundsun.co.jp/\" jsl=\"$t t-zxXzjt1d4B0;$x 0;\" class=\"r-iA_xzYkgkx2Y\">ブリッジSE募集中 - hundsun.co.jp‎</a></h3></body></html>";
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@data-preconnect-urls]");
            if (links == null) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no links contain attribute data-preconnect-urls");
                return;
            }
            foreach(var htmlNode in links)
            {
                var attr = htmlNode.Attributes["data-preconnect-urls"];
                Console.WriteLine(attr.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

you can try it out here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/gMTFV3